# Cannot login to newly installed Ubuntu Server in Virtualbox

Tags: 11.04, server, virtualbox

I've just completed a fresh new installation of Ubuntu 11.04 Server (64 bit) including xfce.  After the installation was complete (along with all the LAMP server components), I started X for the first time and all was good.  After the initial reboot, I get the nice xfce login screen.  I put in my credentials, it suddenly switches to command-line mode for less than half a second and returns me to the pretty xfce login prompt.

The login credentials are correct, as if I intentionally using the wrong username or password, it tells me so.  I managed to capture an image of the terminal window that flashes up and disappears - all just an install script with all [ok] - no errors at all.

Now, this is running on a VBox virtual machine, but that shouldn't really matter - and I've successfully used the same VBox for dozens of other Linux installations - including Ubuntu server 10.04 LTS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok - I'm not sure exactly how, but on my 5th attempt, I got it working and the problem automagically went away.

I think it had to do with VBoxLinuxAddtions... see [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=965016), which gave me a bit of guidance:

First, you need to install VirtualBox guest extensions:

- In the VirtualBox menu, Devices -> "Install Guest Additions"
- Then, mount them: Devices -> Mount CD/DVD-ROM -> CD/DVD-ROM Image
- Select VBoxGuestAdditions.iso

Open a terminal (Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal)

- `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`
- `mount /media/cdrom` (If you get an error that it's already mounted, ignore the error)
- `sudo /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions-x86.run`
- (wait)
- Reboot the virtual machine.

Comment: Ran into the same problem with Ubuntu 14.04.
Followed these instructions, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

To be specific - it was the "sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic" that I had been missing.  Oddly enough, it wasn't a required step in the other Linux installations I had done on VBox - including Ubuntu Server 11.04 running gnome - it seems just xfce (or at least my installation of xfce) was having problems without it...